# Android: Capturing Images and sending them via Socket to an Applet

Tags: java, android, sockets

I want to implement a simple video streaming vor Android. I can send single image shots via TCP Socket, but I have problems to send several images quickly. I use the common Camera functionality with preview, surfaceholder etc.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html

Is my approach wrong, to use this functionality? How can I implement such kind of video streaming?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should give more details, such as how quickly do you want, or what kind of and how large the data is.
Generally speaking, send single image is okay, even several images are still no big problem. However, vedio streaming requires a large amount of bandwidth and CPU speed. And the video should not be sent as images, it could be either a vedio file or vedio streaming, deponds on your requirment.

Answer (score 0):

I did play around with MJPEG for a while. This may give you a hint for a simple way to send video.